# Sorting terms on one line in tab delimted text file

Tags: sorting

My file contains a number of lines all of which contain a tab delimited sequence of terms. I would like to sort these tab delimited terms alphabetically within each line using the 'sort' command but seem to be unable to do it.

Thanks for your help

Markus

[image: file format]

Comment: Sorting using NP++ ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk to sort the fields of each row:

```
awk '{split($0,a);asort(a);for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=a[i];print}' a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
per_row = []

infile = open('Myfile.txt', 'r')

for line in infile:
    per_row.append(line.split('\t'))


sorted = [x for x in sorted(infile)]

print (sorted)
```

above is a python code to sort the file